# Swift 3 URLSession TCP/IP Connection Issues

Tags: networking, tcp

All,

Here is my frustrating problem that I'm out of ideas how to troubleshoot. I have a code to upload a post to a .php script. It's a standard multi-form post request done with a URLSession and dataTask(with: request) method.

I got the following error at home, then I moved to a different home and get the same problem:

error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800045eff0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.somedomain.com/upload.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.somedomain.com/upload.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.})

However, I went out of town on business and it worked fine from the hotel. Then I tried it at another location and it worked fine there too.

SO

- My old home and new home: doesn't work
- Hotel two states away, and
  near my office: works fine

ALSO, old home used cable modem/router combo and new home uses a different device (DSL modem/router combo), so I don't think old home and new home have anything in common.

I've got traceroutes and a wireshark capture file for connections at my new home, hotel, and near my office.

When the problem happens, there is a tcp stream that transfers lots of data, but always gets RST packets from the server before it can finish.

I realize that this appears to be a tcp/ip networking problem more than it is a Swift/Xcode problem, but I'm not sure where exactly the problem lies.

Any troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: "Old home and new home" have something in common: The router (I believe). That'd be the first place I'd look in your case.

Comment: The router is actually not a common element. At the old home was a cable modem/router provided by Time Warner Cable and new home is a DSL modem on CenturyLink.